# Dynamic web twain integrate with Aurelia Js

Tags: aurelia, twain, dynamic-web-twain

Am new to Aurelia Js i need to integrate scanner into my project. Now, i trying to integrate **dynamic web twain** but i don't have a idea to start with Aurelia framework.Any kind of idea to achieve this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Right now - I added Resource folder into my project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AspriseSupport. I did integrated scanner Js

Comment: @sibi The Resource folder is used for distribution. If you don't want to copy the Resource folder, you can include the online JS file: [dynamsoft.webtwain.min.js](https://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/DWT/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.min.js)